# How to use NaiveDateTime.local_now in Elixir

Tags: date, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using `NaiveDateTime.local_now/1` to record time an item is saved in my db and when it is accessed. When I run warnings on my machine with the command `mix compile --warnings-as-errors --force` it records no errors but when I run it on our gitlab runner the pipeline fails wth the error 
`warning: function NaiveDateTime.local_now/0 is undefined or private`

Here's how I've used it `NaiveDateTime.local_now() |> NaiveDateTime.add(900)`

Any insights? I'm using `image: elixir:1.7.4-alpine` as my Elixir image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NaiveDateTime.local_now/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html?#local_now/1) exists since `v1.10.0` as shown in the top right corner of the window in the documentation I linked and which might be seen by navigating to sources of [`v1.7.4`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.4/lib/elixir/lib/calendar/naive_datetime.ex).

There is absolutely no reason to remain on `v1.7.4` in production, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is perfectly backward-compatible. Upgrade your image, or, if it is impossible, backport [the function](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.2/lib/elixir/lib/calendar/naive_datetime.ex#L147-L151) to your own module and call it instead.

```rb
defmodule MyHelpers do
  def local_now(Calendar.ISO) do
    {{year, month, day}, {hour, minute, second}} =
      :erlang.localtime()
    {:ok, ndt} =
      NaiveDateTime.new(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
    ndt
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of checking when NaiveDateTime was released! I just upgraded my image and everything was okay. Thanks again!